# Why should etymology stop where it does?

Tags: etymology

There are many words whose origin is traced through Middle English and/or French to Latin or Greek, and then it just stops there.

Case in point: the word "etymology" itself:

**1350-1400; Middle English < Latin etymologia < Greek etymología, equivalent to etymológ (os) studying the true meanings and values of words ( étymo (s) true (see etymon ) + lógos word, reason) + -ia -y3**

So it really means "true reason" (for being, I suppose).

I'm not saying that we should strive to trace everything back to Sanskrit. However, before Greece, there was ancient Egypt.

The Greeks and Egyptians knew each other well from very early on. ("O Solon, Solon, you Hellenes are but children!" exclaims an Egyptian in one of Plato's dialogues). It would have only been natural for the inquisitive Greeks to borrow a few dozen words from their more advanced neighbors.

In their heyday, the Greeks documented everything they could, and the Romans documented and indexed everything they got their hands on, and then the medieval monks did a tremendous job preserving a huge portion of it all until finally Johannes Gutenberg invented his proverbial printing press, which quickly resulted in the creation of backup copies of everything pertaining to antiquity.

And yet nowhere in the dictionary do you see a word whose etymology is described as "from Middle English - from Latin - from Greek - from Egyptian."

Now why is that?

Comment: Why would everything be able to be traced to Sanskrit anyway?

Comment: @emacsomancer: Because at some point it was considered the closest thing to the original proto-Indo-European language. Though disputed today, this view has some validity. Certain basic words in different European languages have common ancestors that predate recorded history. Words such as snow, water, sky, etc, sound like variations on the same theme in Romance, Germanic, Slavic and Baltic languages. The Finno-Ugric group is the only one that stands out like a sore thumb, but they tell me linguists have managed to work it out recently.

Comment: Considering Sanskrit the closest thing to PIE went out of fashion long ago.  Finno-Ugric is not Indo-European, so I'm not sure what "linguists" have managed to work out about it.

Comment: @emacsomancer: Fashions come and go. "Indo-European" is a very vague term to begin with. Similarities with French and English have been found in Hungarian (Finno-Ugric) and Hebrew (Semitic) as far back as the early 1800's, as attested to in the first chapter of Byron's "Don Juan." Lighten up, chief.

Comment: 99% of dictionaries out there will not chase after Proto-Indo-European. It's simply beyond their scope. Also, not many Egyptian words got loaned in (and Egyptian was Afro-Asiatic, and meanwhile Latin, Sanskrit, and Greek were Indo-European.)

Comment: The solution is: get a good etymological dictionary. It should trace the etymology as far back as possible, including Proto-Indo-European or Egyptian. I am not aware of good etymological dictionaries in English, although it is likely that they exist; but, if you know another language, you can look up a cognate in a good etymological dictionary in that language. Dutch has a good etymological dictionary online, accessible through the Etymologiebank: http://www.etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/lamp. Good dictionaries for Latin and Greek are De Vaan and Chantraine, respectively.

Comment: The number of Greek words derived from Egyptian is microscopic.

Comment: @Ricky It's not vague at all anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are essentially asking two questions:

1. Why aren't there etymologies for an English word going back to Ancient Egyptian?

This question is easily answered: Because such words are rare beasts and you won't find many. Ancient Greek and Latin didn't borrow many words from Ancient Egyptian.

2. Why do etymological dictionaries stop where they stop?

This is a pragmatic decision of the compilers and editors. Space matters, and the time to compile the dictionary matters, too. For compound words they usually stop with stating the components, for derived words with the derivation, and for basic words the deeper relations are noted. You will often find notes see this or that lemma for more information.

Comment: For a counter example, consider _oasis_, which certainly comes via Latin from Greek, but Greek in turn borrowed it from ancient Egyptian _wḫ'-ṭ_ (according to the OED).

Comment: The majority of Greek and Latin words (and English, German, Hindi, and Russian words too) derive from the unrecorded language _Proto Indo-european_. Some dictionaries do give these roots where they are known.

Comment: @Colin Fine: I was alluding to this fact with the formulation "deeper relations". Some dictionaries give PIE roots, other give comparable words from other IE languages.

Comment: I know; but it is not clear whether the OP understands this.